# SharePoint 2013 Community - can't pull documents from document library in search result

Tags: 2013, document-library, search-results, community

I am using SharePoint 2013 Community and I am trying to show the list of pdf documents in the search result. I have a document library in the root site and i have uploaded all the documents in there.

I have dragged the search result control in a page in the sub site and I am writing following query:

{searchboxquery} path:"http://server-sharep/Shared%20Documents/*"

It i just listing this page in search result. Do you know how to pull list of PDF documents from the library?
Home - Documents
server/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave the Path and remove the {searchboxquery}. You can add FileExtension:pdf to only return PDF and (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem") to only return documents.

so your final query will be:

```
path:"http://server-sharep/Shared%20Documents/*" FileExtension:pdf (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem")
```

Comment: No it didn't solve the issue. When i changed the query and click on "test query" then it rendered 0 results. I looked further and went in the Central Admin to see if "Path" it self is searchable and when i went into the "Search schema" and tried to make "Path" searchable then it gave me this error "The settings could not be saved because of an internal error: The search application 'a279694a-3b46-45fd-bf6d-768e82ecbd2a' on server SERVER-SHARE did not finish loading. View the event logs on the affected server for more information."

Comment: so is the Search Service itself working or not? Can you search for any document from the Search Center?

Comment: I think it is working but it doesn't pull the list of documents in the search result.
for example: if i type this "{searchboxquery} path:"http://server-sharep/Shared%20Documents/*"" then it just shows the documentlibrary page "RelevantResults (1)
Home - Documents
server-sharep/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx"

Comment: so how about you go to the search center and type in this path:"server-sharep/Shared%20Documents*" *

Comment: How to get to the search center?